Segementation fault error with gem Pycall
I have a rails project using pycall and pandas.
I use these gems in a dedicated service. It works on production (heroku) and in a local rails console, I can run some data calculations.
But in a local rails server (I call the service from a controller), it doesn't work anymore: every time pycall is called, the server crashes.
Apparently, the error comes from pytypeobject_wrapper.rb (method from the gem pycall) but I have absolutely no idea why and I don't know how to fix it.
Backtrace:
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pycall-1.5.1/lib/pycall/pytypeobject_wrapper.rb:24: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000010
web.1  | ruby 3.2.3 (2024-01-18 revision 52bb2ac0a6) [arm64-darwin23]
web.1  | 
web.1  | -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
web.1  |    See Crash Report log file in one of the following locations:
web.1  |      * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
web.1  |      * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
web.1  |    for more details.
web.1  | Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.
web.1  | 
web.1  | -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
web.1  | c:0091 p:---- s:0656 e:000655 CFUNC  :call_object
web.1  | c:0090 p:0012 s:0650 e:000648 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pycall-1.5.1/lib/pycall/pytypeobject_wrapper.rb:24
web.1  | c:0089 p:0076 s:0644 e:000642 METHOD /Users/xxx/Work/projectX/app/services/resource/calculation_service.rb:28
web.1  | c:0088 p:0015 s:0631 e:000630 METHOD /Users/xxx/Work/projectX/app/services/resource/application_service.rb:8
web.1  | c:0087 p:0014 s:0624 e:000623 METHOD /Users/xxx/Work/projectX/app/controllers/admin/resources_controller.rb:42
web.1  | c:0086 p:0010 s:0620 e:000619 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_rende
web.1  | c:0085 p:0011 s:0613 e:000612 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215
web.1  | c:0084 p:0022 s:0606 e:000605 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165
web.1  | c:0083 p:0008 s:0601 e:000600 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234
web.1  | c:0082 p:0048 s:0598 e:000596 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118
web.1  | c:0081 p:0018 s:0588 e:000587 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/turbo-rails-2.0.5/lib/turbo-rails.rb:24
web.1  | c:0080 p:0016 s:0582 e:000581 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/turbo-rails-2.0.5/app/controllers/concerns/turbo/request_id_track
web.1  | c:0079 p:0127 s:0577 e:000576 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127
web.1  | c:0078 p:0105 s:0568 E:001618 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138
web.1  | c:0077 p:0006 s:0559 E:001488 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233
web.1  | c:0076 p:0008 s:0552 e:000551 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23
web.1  | c:0075 p:0009 s:0546 e:000545 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:6
web.1  | c:0074 p:0010 s:0540 e:000539 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
web.1  | c:0073 p:0022 s:0537 e:000536 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter
web.1  | c:0072 p:0023 s:0529 e:000528 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
web.1  | c:0071 p:0084 s:0523 e:000522 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:6
web.1  | c:0070 p:0017 s:0517 e:000516 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:25
web.1  | c:0069 p:0015 s:0512 e:000511 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.
web.1  | c:0068 p:0063 s:0506 e:000505 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151
web.1  | c:0067 p:0035 s:0499 e:000498 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39
web.1  | c:0066 p:0017 s:0491 e:000490 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188
web.1  | c:0065 p:0033 s:0484 e:000483 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251
web.1  | c:0064 p:0010 s:0477 e:000476 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49
web.1  | c:0063 p:0036 s:0469 e:000468 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32
web.1  | c:0062 p:0006 s:0461 e:000460 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18
web.1  | c:0061 p:0026 s:0456 e:000455 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48
web.1  | c:0060 p:0109 s:0451 e:000450 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50 [FINISH]
web.1  | c:0059 p:---- s:0438 e:000437 CFUNC  :each
web.1  | c:0058 p:0008 s:0434 e:000433 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32
web.1  | c:0057 p:0027 s:0429 e:000428 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852
web.1  | c:0056 p:0026 s:0423 e:000422 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266
web.1  | c:0055 p:0005 s:0412 e:000411 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260
web.1  | c:0054 p:0015 s:0407 e:000406 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704
web.1  | c:0053 p:0016 s:0397 e:000396 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36 [FINISH]
web.1  | c:0052 p:---- s:0394 e:000393 CFUNC  :catch
web.1  | c:0051 p:0050 s:0389 e:000388 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
web.1  | c:0050 p:0028 s:0383 e:000382 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15
web.1  | c:0049 p:0007 s:0374 e:000373 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/etag.rb:27
web.1  | c:0048 p:0034 s:0363 e:000362 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40
web.1  | c:0047 p:0007 s:0354 e:000353 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/head.rb:12
web.1  | c:0046 p:0015 s:0346 e:000345 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:3
web.1  | c:0045 p:0015 s:0336 e:000335 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy
web.1  | c:0044 p:0026 s:0322 e:000321 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266
web.1  | c:0043 p:0005 s:0311 e:000310 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260
web.1  | c:0042 p:0015 s:0306 e:000305 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704
web.1  | c:0041 p:0014 s:0296 e:000295 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:603
web.1  | c:0040 p:0008 s:0291 e:000290 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27
web.1  | c:0039 p:0024 s:0288 e:000287 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99
web.1  | c:0038 p:0009 s:0279 e:000278 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26
web.1  | c:0037 p:0016 s:0272 e:000271 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14
web.1  | c:0036 p:0022 s:0263 e:000262 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_except
web.1  | c:0035 p:0015 s:0257 e:000256 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.
web.1  | c:0034 p:0007 s:0246 e:000245 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132
web.1  | c:0033 p:0069 s:0240 e:000239 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28 [FINISH]
web.1  | c:0032 p:---- s:0230 e:000229 CFUNC  :catch
web.1  | c:0031 p:0006 s:0225 e:000224 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17
web.1  | c:0030 p:0015 s:0218 e:000217 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.r
web.1  | c:0029 p:0037 s:0211 E:0026a0 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40
web.1  | c:0028 p:0007 s:0199 e:000198 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25
web.1  | c:0027 p:0003 s:0196 e:000195 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99
web.1  | c:0026 p:0012 s:0193 e:000192 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37
web.1  | c:0025 p:0015 s:0187 e:000186 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99
web.1  | c:0024 p:0028 s:0181 e:000180 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25
web.1  | c:0023 p:0027 s:0175 e:000174 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13
web.1  | c:0022 p:0034 s:0170 e:000169 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93
web.1  | c:0021 p:0032 s:0164 e:000163 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26
web.1  | c:0020 p:0057 s:0158 e:000157 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24
web.1  | c:0019 p:0013 s:0152 e:000151 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22
web.1  | c:0018 p:0019 s:0142 e:000141 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache
web.1  | c:0017 p:0007 s:0135 e:000134 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:
web.1  | c:0016 p:0015 s:0132 e:000131 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:
web.1  | c:0015 p:0009 s:0127 e:000126 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:
web.1  | c:0014 p:0016 s:0118 e:000117 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14
web.1  | c:0013 p:0018 s:0109 e:000108 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23
web.1  | c:0012 p:0007 s:0104 e:000103 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110
web.1  | c:0011 p:0050 s:0092 e:000091 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorizatio
web.1  | c:0010 p:0156 s:0086 e:000085 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-cors-2.0.1/lib/rack/cors.rb:102
web.1  | c:0009 p:0016 s:0072 e:000071 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:530
web.1  | c:0008 p:0017 s:0066 e:000065 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:252
web.1  | c:0007 p:0007 s:0061 e:000060 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/request.rb:77
web.1  | c:0006 p:0015 s:0058 e:000057 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340
web.1  | c:0005 p:0187 s:0053 e:000052 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/request.rb:76
web.1  | c:0004 p:0097 s:0032 e:000031 METHOD /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/server.rb:443 [FINISH]
web.1  | c:0003 p:---- s:0020 e:000019 IFUNC 
web.1  | c:0002 p:0083 s:0017 e:000014 BLOCK  /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147 [FINISH]
web.1  | c:0001 p:---- s:0003 e:000002 DUMMY  [FINISH]
web.1  | 
web.1  | -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-cors-2.0.1/lib/rack/cors.rb:102:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:60:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:26:in `collect_events'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:61:in `block in call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:603:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23:in `process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/turbo-rails-2.0.5/app/controllers/concerns/turbo/request_id_tracking.rb:10:in `turbo_tracking_request_id'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/turbo-rails-2.0.5/lib/turbo-rails.rb:24:in `with_request_id'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165:in `process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.6/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/Work/projectX/app/controllers/admin/resources_controller.rb:42:in `recalculate_result'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/Work/projectX/app/services/resource/application_service.rb:8:in `call'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/Work/projectX/app/services/resource/calculation_service.rb:28:in `perform'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pycall-1.5.1/lib/pycall/pytypeobject_wrapper.rb:24:in `new'
web.1  | /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pycall-1.5.1/lib/pycall/pytypeobject_wrapper.rb:24:in `call_object'
web.1  | 
web.1  | -- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
web.1  |   x0: 0x000060000551e658  x1: 0x0000000000000001  x2: 0x000000016c6e81b0
web.1  |   x3: 0x000000010852b404  x4: 0x000000000000000d  x5: 0x0000000000002630
web.1  |   x6: 0x000060000551e630  x7: 0x000000016c6e49d0 x18: 0x0000000000000000
web.1  |  x19: 0x0000000108fb8e08 x20: 0x0000000000000001 x21: 0x000060000551e658
web.1  |  x22: 0x0000000000000001 x23: 0x0000000000000001 x24: 0x0000000107f0dc48
web.1  |  x25: 0x000439d100010005 x26: 0x00006000018e13b0 x27: 0x0000000000000000
web.1  |  x28: 0x0000000055550083  lr: 0xc91e000108cd1888  fp: 0x000000016c6e4fe0
web.1  |   sp: 0x000000016c6e4fc0
web.1  | 



App rails config:

Ruby 3.2.3
Rails 7.0.4
Python 3.12.2
requirement.txt
networkx==2.5
numpy==1.24.0
pandas==1.5.2



I also try to run my server with virtualenv but it doesn't change anything, I have the same error.

I'm having the some problem, pycall works great from our tests, but when I use it from Rails, instant segfault. My initial suspicion is this has something to do with pre-fork/post-fork behavior with puma?

I have a minimal repro of my issue here: https://github.com/snickell/pycall_puma_crash, do you have an example of a pandas call that causes a crash for you @Sovalina?

Hi @Seth, I created a minimal copy of my project if it can help: here

Same exact problem.
